# License for using background music in my video?

Tags: copyright, music

I want to use the song Spirit of Life by Blackmill as background music video but I wasn't able to find any information about license to use this song. I tried to contact Blackmill as well but no response. I'm trying not to use a different song because it works so well with my video currently. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Having licensed music for videos I've produced; from having custom tracks re-recorded by one of Audio Jungles top artists (1 Million in Sales); to one hit wonders who had radio airplay; to even Katy Perry...

You need to find out what Label the album is under; meaning, who owns the rights.

Blackmill will have no say, unless they own the masters which I doubt.

The label information should be easilly found on the CD/Album info.

Contact the label; and they will either have a licensing department or they will refer you to their agency.

It is a time consuming process; there is a lot of back and forth, and it could be expensive. Very. If they are under a large label; and they don't have an agreement with a "licencing agency" like ExtremeMusic; which basically mass sells known artists and because they do so on a large scale basis they have a basic rate sheet; 1 song for x use for x type of duplication used in x such a way = this price;  if they don't have that track on a easy to buy list; it's going to involve a custom negotiation where money talks and if you don't have the money...  don't expect a return call.

Contacting Blackmill or even their manager/management is likely going to prove a waste of time.

Comment: Thanks @Martin, it seems to me that he self-released his album though: https://www.discogs.com/label/259268-Not-On-Label-Blackmill-Self-released

Comment: If self released and they aren't under contract with a label; then your approach of contacting the band; or their booking manager; whoever handles their gigs; etc; would be your best bet. Just be persistent. But not pushy. Complement their work as well; their sound; as well of their work... that helps.